# Figuring out the importance of each component in a circuit

Tags: led, capacitor, ltspice

This is the blueprint of a circuit that I've got to build on a breadboard, but I've a lot of questions regarding this.

[image]

1. In the first part of the circuit, there is a V_cc of 10V, a diode D1, a LED D2, two resistors R7,R8 and C3. I assume that the purpose of the two resistors is to drive safe current through the led D2, but what are the purposes of D1 and cap C3?
2. Also, the voltage measured at the node after D1 gives a value between 9.3570 and 9.3530, an oscillating waveform. Why is this so? It should have been a fixed one, considering D1's breakdown voltage were given to be 75V, and an average forward current of 0.2A.
3. Also, if I were to judge whether the circuit worked simply as a voltage source or current source, do I need to check the series internal resistance? If so, is it just the series resistance of R7 and R8?

Can someone help me out in these? I would like to ask other follow-up questions, I'm an absolute beginner in electronics. Thanks.

Comment: D1 is reverse-voltage protection against wrong connection of the 10 V supply. C3 provides a proximate source of ready current for the switching pulses of the multivibrator. And you have a lot of questions there, which suggest that even answering those will just lead to another dozen of them (which you admit may happen.) How much of this circuit do you follow? And why do you have to build this? What's the context here?

Comment: I am supposed to build this as a part of an assignment, but I'm unable to figure out a lot of things here. So I decided to clear my doubts before going on to build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D1 protects the circuit if the voltage supply is connected backwards. C3 reduces voltage ripple from the supply; giving a quieter DC voltage source for the rest of the circuit.

Diodes do not prevent oscillation. They block reverse current. Your diode has a 3 mV ripple on top of a 0.65 V forward voltage. The diode voltage and current never reverse, so the diode never stops conducting. Also, 3 mV is a very small ripple. That's not enough to turn a diode on and off even in a simulation.

I'm not sure what you mean by "whether the circuit [works] simply as a voltage source or a current source". Do you mean Vsupply and the nearby components? Current sources are usually made with transistors or voltage regulators. One characteristic of a good current source is a high source resistance. Your voltage supply has a small series resistance, so it doesn't act like a current source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't seem to follow "1.65 forward voltage". Is it 0.65? Also, if I were to apply KVL  for this part, do I need to consider the 3mV ripple as well? Also, does the led D2 cause any ripple?

Comment: You said the voltage at the node after D1 was ~8.35 V. Vsupply is 10 V. 10 - 8.35 = 1.65 V. Regardless, the ripple should be much smaller than the forward voltage across the diode.

Diodes don't cause ripple. I would ignore the ripple. The rest of the circuit looks like an oscillator -- if that's right, the ripple is coming from there.

Comment: I expect the 1.65 volts is a typo, and should be 0.65 volts - at least, that's the voltage I'd expect across a 1N4148.  An LED will not cause ripple.  Any ripple will be from the flip-flop formed by Q1 and Q2 as the current they draw will vary as they flip and flop.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. It'd be 9.35. Sorry for my typo.

Comment: So, the oscillation between 9.3570 and 9.3530 is due to the ripple right?

Comment: @electrovolt What's happening at node 1 (the Q1/RC1/C12 connection)? If the transistors are switching on and off, the supply current will vary, which would produce a tiny voltage ripple across the diode.