# Figuring out the importance of components in a circuit-2

Tags: filter, multivibrator, kirchhoffs-laws

This is a follow-up question for [this qs which I asked earlier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/581209/figuring-out-the-importance-of-each-component-in-a-circuit/581212?noredirect=1#comment1521184_581212)

Here is the full specifications-[image]

The simulation gives me a current of 6.5 mA through D1 and 833 micro-A through D2. Also, I get the voltage at the collector of Q1 to be 1.9V, probably due to the voltage divider.
These are my doubts-

1)Analyzing the circuit, is it possible to work out the KVL to find the current through the diodes here, and also the V_cc for the multivibrator? I would like some hints to that, as I've been trying but unable to figure it out.

2. Why do we have RC12 and RC22 connected to the ground? Probably to step down the voltage at the collector of Q2. Does the next part of the circuit force us to connect a resistor load from the collector to the ground? Basically, what would be the purpose of RC1 and RC2?

3)Also, R1C1 and R2C2 cascaded work as low and high filters right?

4)What is the purpose of Q3?

These questions have been bugging me, and a good explanation would really be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please refer to components by identifier ... `4)What is the purpose of Q3?` is less reading

Comment: not a very useful circuit to produce a small triangle wave